# Can't click to submit button in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to click a button with Selenium in python but it doesn't work.
that is a button and i wanna click it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipqpR.png)

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, the error you are getting and the html of the element you want to click.

Comment: I've put an image to there already

Comment: Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)